# ClojureScript: Using Jayq to get value of attribute

Tags: jquery, clojurescript

I was wondering if anyone knows how you can get the value of an attribute from a webpages HTML using jayq in ClojureScript.

I have done this so far:

```
(ns jquerytest.core)

(def jquery (js* "$"))
 (jquery
     (fn []
         (-> (jquery "#w3s")
             (.attr "href" "http://www.duckduckgo.com")
         )
     )
 )
```

This code does what it should and changes the "href" value in the attribute "w3s" from http://www.google.com to http://www.duckduckgo.com.

From what I know of jQuery (on which jayq was wrapped around), getting the value of an attribute is as simple as:

```
var hyref = $(this).attr('href');
alert(hyref);
```

So, I've been trying to model a similar behavior in my clojurescript (but simply writing to the screen etc). Here is a set of two example attempts:

(1)

```
(defn attr-link [] 
     (doto (jquery ".link") 
           (.html) 
           (println)
     )
)
```

This method was only to see if I could get anything from the attribute "link" at all, I did manage to get this printed out to the screen:

```
function jquerytest$core$y(){ var G__6988 = jquerytest.core.jquery.call(null,".link"); G__6988.html(); cljs.core.println.call(null,G__6988); return G__6988; }
```

(2)

```
(defn getVal [] 
     (-> (jquery "#w3s")
         (.attr "href")
     )
)
```

I was hoping that someone might be willing to point out my own stupidity by talking me through how to one should actually go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while of searching, I managed to stumble upon the answer myself. Using the [Dommy](https://github.com/plumatic/dommy) library (dom in my code) I managed to retrieve the href value of a "a" tag.

```
  (ns hello-world.core
  (:require [clojure.browser.repl :as repl] [dommy.core :as dom])
      (defn get-link-value 
        []
        (println (-> (dom/sel1 "#w3s")
          (dom/attr :href)
        )   
      )
```

This is by no means probably the best solution to the problem, but it is the only one I managed to find at this time.